# Page_Load firing multiple times?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

We have been dealing with an error for the last couple of days, so we created a small page (quick and dirty programming, my apologies in advance) that connects to the database, checks if a document exists, and displays some data related to the document. If there is an exception, an email is sent with the exception information and some log data.

Here's a simplified version of the code (short explanation below):

```
namespace My.Namespace
{
   public partial class myClass : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
       private static SqlConnection conn = null;
       private static SqlCommand command1 = null;
       private static SqlCommand command2 = null;
       private static string log = "";

       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           if (!Page.IsPostBack)
           {
               try
               {
                    log += "START\n";
                    string docId = Request.QueryString["docId"];

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(docName))
                    {
                        bool docExists = doesDocExist(docId);

                        if (docExists == true)
                        {
                            string docMetadata = getMetadata(docId);
                            Response.Write(docMetadata);
                        }
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        // display error message
                    }
                }
                catch (sqlException sqlex) 
                {
                    // process exception
                    sendErrorMessage(sqlex.Message);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // process exception
                    sendErrorMessage(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        private static bool doesDocExist(string docId)
        {
            log += "In doesDocExist\n";
            bool docExists = false;

            try
            {
                // open db connection (conn)
                string cmd = String.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM docs WHERE id='{0}'", docId);
                command1 = new SqlCommand(cmd, conn);
                conn.Open();
                var val = command1.ExecuteScalar();
                int numberOfRows = int.Parse(val.ToString());
                if (numberOfRows > 0) { docExists = true; }
            }
            finally
            {
                // close db connection (conn)
            }

            return docExists;
        }

        protected string getMetadata(string docId)
        {
            log += "In getMetadata\n";
            string docMetadata = "";

            try
            {
                // open db connection (conn)
                string cmd = String.Format("SELECT metadata FROM docs WHERE id='{0}'", docID);
                command2 = new SqlCommand(cmd, conn);
                conn.Open();

                SqlDataReader rReader = command2.ExecuteReader();
                if (rReader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (rReader.Read())
                    {
                        // process metadata
                        docMetadata += DOCMETADATA;
                    }
                }
            }

            return docMetadata;
        }

        public static void sendErrorMessage(string messageText)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(messageText);

            // Send string log via email
        }    
    }
}
```

I know it's too long, so here is a quick description of it. We have a class with the `Page_Load` method and three other methods:

- doesDocExists: returns a bool value indicating if an document ID is in the database.
- getMetadata: returns a string with metadata related to the document.
- sendErrorMessage: sends an email with a log generated during the page.

From `Page_Load` we call `doesDocExists`. If the value returned is *true*, then it calls `getMetadata` and displays the value on the screen. If there's any error, it is caught in the `Page_Load` and sent as an email.

The problem is that when there's an error, instead of getting an email with the log (i.e.: START - In Function1 - In Function2), the log appears 100 times in the email (i.e.: START - In Function1 - In Function2 - Start - In Function1 - In Function2 - START... and so on), as if `Page_Load` was fired that many times.

We read online (http://www.craigwardman.com/blog/index.php/2009/01/asp-net-multiple-page-load-problem/) that it could be because of the PostBack. So, we added the condition `if (!Page.IsPostBack)`, but the result is still the same.

Is there any reason why `Page_Load` would be triggered multiple times? Or is it that we are doing something wrong with the log variable and/or the try/catch that causes this behavior?

Comment: So you only get one e-mail? Not 100 e-mails?

Comment: That's correct, we get one email with 100 times the same text. To verify that it was not 100 copies of the log variable, we added an integer variable that increases +1 at the beginning of `Page_Load`. The result was an email with "Start 1 - In Function 1 - In Function2 - Start 2 - In Function1 - In Function2 - Start 3..." and like that until "Start 100"

Comment: Could you check if there is any loop ? What did you find when you debug it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log may be long because you are declaring the  string log as ***static***.  Does it need to be static?

Comment: We have implemented this suggestion but cannot see the results until the exception is triggered. Once we get the email, we'll see if this did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static SqlConnection conn = null;
private static SqlCommand command1 = null;
private static SqlCommand command2 = null;
private static string log = "";
```

The problem is that **log** is **Singleton** along with other properties.

Whenever you access that page, you append text to **log** property which ends up being `START - In Function1 - In Function2 - Start - In Function1 - In Function2 - START... and so on`

Base on your scenario, you do not need to use **Singleton** inside myClass.

***FYI:*** Since I do not know the rest of your code, ensure to instantiate `conn, command1, command2`.

Comment: This is a simple web page that we access using a browser; every time that we refresh it, log will get new values appended instead of being initialized to ""? I need to look into Singleton and how it works

Comment: `every time that we refresh it, log will get new values appended instead of being initialized to ""?` **Yes.**

Comment: We don't normally use static property in ASP.Net Code Behind, *although we use it in IoC container, Extension methods, Caching, Singleton Pattern and so on.*

Answer (score 0):

If your page load functions are execute twice because post back is possible when you clicking on the button or link, so should check it and run by the below

```
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
 try
               {
                    log += "START\n";
                    string docId = Request.QueryString["docId"];

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(docName))
                    {
                        bool docExists = doesDocExist(docId);

                        if (docExists == true)
                        {
                            string docMetadata = getMetadata(docId);
                            Response.Write(docMetadata);
                        }
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        // display error message
                    }
                }
                catch (sqlException sqlex) 
                {
                    // process exception
                    sendErrorMessage(sqlex.Message);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // process exception
                    sendErrorMessage(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```